# C# Increment Numeric String

Tags: c#, string, auto-increment

I have a static string:

static string SERIAL = "000";

I need to increment it by 1 on a certain condition. For example, the value should be like this:

```
001
002
003
```

and so on.

I have tried different ways but haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: why are you using a string?

Comment: Indeed, use an `int`, increment it, then just call `mySerialInt.ToString("000")`

Comment: show us your code and ask with some of your own findings...

Comment: Can't you make it an `int` so you can increment it and cast it to a string, formatting it with additional zeros when required.

Comment: Yeah, can't you use an int?

Comment: because the value should always be 3 digits i.e. from 000 to 999

Comment: @Sara: See my comment, use the `ToString` overload where you can pass a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to it having it always display with 3 digits.

Comment: As Chris Sinclair said, you should keep the variable type closest to the operations that will be performed upon it; in your case doing an increment is much simpler and easier to understand when the value is an int versus a string. Conversely, if you were concatenating values together, then it would make much more sense to be working with a string versus an int. Keep values in their most organic form and then apply formatting to render them in particular abstractions when necessary.

Comment: Thank you all for quick responses. @Chris Sinclair  your answer solved my problem and it is so simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have the serial value as a integer and define a getter which will return the value as a string in the desired format. This way you can simply increment the numeric value of the serial.

As an example:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Counter.SerialString);
        Counter.Serial++;
        Console.WriteLine(Counter.SerialString);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Counter
    {
        public static int Serial;

        public static string SerialString
        {
            get
            {
                return Serial.ToString("000");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the PadLeft method on the ToString method.

```
        int n = 000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            n++;
            Console.WriteLine(n.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));               
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Heres the method header
public string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar);

Answer (score 0):

If the serial is always 3 digit long, You can use an integer and when You need it as a string, just call its `ToString()` method.